# How to implement multiple functions on single push button

Tags: stm32, interrupts, gpio

I am using a STM32 Nucleo MCU and trying to pull a multi-function single-button method.

I need a way to implement this form of functionality for a single push-button:

- Push 1: function 1
- Push 2: function 2
- Push 3: function 3
- Push 4: function 4 + reset/loop back to before Push 1

I tried using a sort of counter variable like:

```
if(GPIO_Pin == Pin){
    Counter++;
    if(Counter == 1){
        function1();
    }else if(Counter == 2){
        function2();
    }else if(Counter == 3){
        function3();
    }else if(Counter == 4){
        function4();
        Counter = 0;
    }
}
```

But then the problem I faced is - I had to place these conditional statements inside a `while(1)` loop - so it keeps running. Here the `Counter` variable becomes unreliable since the while loop will increment the `Counter` variable too many times.

I tried using GPIO_EXTI - which are interrupt callbacks. Even when I call the functions using with **External Interrupt Mode with Rising Edge trigger detection** I am having the same problem with the counter variable increment multiple times.

```
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
  if(GPIO_Pin == Pin){
            Counter++;
            if(Counter== 1){
                func1();            
            }else if(Counter== 2){
                func2();
            }else if(Counter== 3){
                func3();
            }       
    }
}
```

Is there any way around this rather than just use more buttons? Or any way to implement a multi-function single-button method different from the counter method I thought of?

Comment: First you will need to learn about *debouncing*.  Likely what you want to do is to ignore the input for maybe 150 ms after each time you detect it pressed.  And you may not want to run this out of an interrupt service routine, but either set a volatile flag to trigger a run at an opportune time in the main loop.  Or if the main loop is simple, cease using an interrupt at all and simply poll the gpio.

Comment: @ChrisStratton What do you mean by a volatile flag? is it the same thing as an ISR request handler ? I tried using a small delay in the ISR but the interrupt seemed to get frozen right there and was no longer respond.. still no clue why that happen. I could simply try your idea in the main loop but it requires the user to hold the button for a certain amount of time correct?

Comment: @Ruthless volatile is a keyword like const. It means always read from the source and never read from cache (or optimize things somehow so it doesn't read from the source) since the value might change at any time

Comment: @Toor volatile does not have anything in common with cache. It does not guarantee cache coherency.

Comment: @P__J__ Nowhere did I say it guarantees cache coherency.

Comment: @Toor you did `and never read from cache`.  volatile just informs the compiler that the object is side effect prone

Comment: @P__J__ I looked into it again and apparently compilers can optimize repeated accesses by re-reading the value of the variable previously loaded into a register if surrounding code has made no changes to that variable. Some people think of that as a form of caching. Volatile stops stuff like that from happening. That's what I mean.

Comment: @Toor `Some people think of that as a form of caching` I think you are alone in this opinion as it does not have anything common with caching. It is just simple optimization and it does not happen if the optimizations are off.

Comment: @Ruthless many simple main loops would be fast enough to see a user pushing a button quickly.  If yours is too slow for that, then use the interrupt to detect that they did, set a flag (declared volatile as explained by PJ, ignore Toor's mistaken claims) and increment your count in the main loop.  **But then have your main loop ignore the button or flag or disable the ISR for a fraction of a second to avoid spurious activation on "contact bounce"** which typically follows each legitimate push.  Really you should wait until the button has been *released* for a fraction of a second.

Comment: @P__J__ Go read around. Some people call it that. Either way, this is getting into an argument about semantics and disabling optimizations is throwing the baby out with the bathwater.